# iPhone memory crash: signal 0

Tags: iphone, memory, crash

I'm developing an iPhone app which displays some tiles from a map. I've got a thread which loads tile's from internet or filesystem. This is an endless thread

```
while( true ){ //get tile into cache }
```

Unfortunateley after displaying much tiles the application chrashes with signal 0, which means that im out of memory..

My idea is that in this endless thread the tiles are loaded as autorelease, and are nog autoreleased..

Basically im doing this in my endless thread:

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
while( true ){
    UIImage * img = nil;
    NSFileHandle * tile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
    if( tile ){
        NSData * data = [tile readDataToEndOfFile];
        if( data ){
            img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            local = YES;
        }
    }
    if( img == nil ){
        NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/%@.png", todoKey ] ];
        img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url options:NSDataReadingMapped error:&error] ];
    }

    if( img != nil ){
        [cache addObject:img]; //cache is an array of tiles
    }

    [img release];
    [self cleanupCache]; //method to check if cache is full, and if so remove's objects from it
}
[pool release];
```

Im thinking that the autoreleasepool doesn't clean up the "dead" references from time to time, and all the tiles are kept in memory. When i check with instruments-leaks there aren't any memory leaks, but the 'live-memory' keeps adding up..

Any idea's why this is happening and how i can prevent it?

Comment: why do you need an infinite loop?

Comment: In this loop i'm downloading tiles on demand, if my view asks: 'do you've got these tiles?" the thread takes care of downloading them and putting them in a cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should swap the first 2 lines of the program:

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
while( true ){
  ...
  [pool release];
}
```

should be

```
while( true ){
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  ...
  [pool release];
}
```

Currently, after the first trip through your loop, the NSAutoreleasePool you have created will be released. After this, all autoreleased objects will be added to a different NSAutoreleasePool higher in the call stack. I suspect this parent autorelease pool is never released while your program is running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, putting the pool in the while loop greatly improved memory usage. However there was another culprit: NSURLCache.. I found the solution over here:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/52972-cfdata-memory-problem.html

Answer (score 0):

```
if( img != nil ){
 [cache addObject:img];
```

`cache` still holds reference of all the objects you have added. You should probably remove objects which you wont be using.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, but i've already taken care of that, sorry for not telling. After each download-action i check if my cache is full (x amount of objects).. If so i cleanup the cache and call [cache removeObjectAtIndex:i] to remove it.

Comment: Ok how about your variable tile?

Comment: Its an autoreleased object:
NSFileHandle * tile = [NSFileHandle gileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the indention in your code, I hope I got it right. The improved indention makes one problem obvious:

You are releasing a already released object, your pool.

Try to move `NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];` inside the loop.

But most likely you should get rid of the loop in the first place.

Another problem is that you don't set img to nil. If there is a valid `img` in the first run of the loop the code will think it's valid for all other loop runs that follow. If you remove img somewhere from the cache (and the object img points to gets deallocated) you send a retain to a deallocated object when you try to add it to the cache.

Add `img = nil;` at the beginning of your loop.

Comment: Hiya, thanks for fixing it.. But one thing has gone wrong.. The [pool release] happens outside the while(true) loop (actually never)...

You say i've got to get rid of the loop, but the meaning of this thread is downloading tiles on demand, if my view asks: 'do you've got these tiles?" the thread takes care of downloading them and putting them in a cache..

Also on top of my loop, after while(true), i've put UIImage * img = nil;, so that this image is only in the loop.. But still it doesn't fix my problem ..